# Grammar for order insensitive command line options in antlr4

Tags: command-line, antlr4

I am using Antlr4 for command line parsing.
The format of my grammar is
Command: subcommand1 | subcommand2
subcommand1: 'sub1' option1 option2
subcommand2: 'sub2' option3 option4
option1 : '-option1' ID
option2 : '-option2' ID
option3 : '-option3' ID
option4 : '-option4' ID
ID : [a-zA-Z0-9]+

I want the options for each subcommand to be order insensitive
For e.g subcommand -option1 ABC -option2 PQR should be considered as a valid input
As well as subcommand -option2 PQR -option1 ABC should also be considered as a valid input

One brute force way of changing the grammar could be
subcommand1: 'sub1' ( option1 option2 | option2 option1)
subcommand2: 'sub2' ( option3 option4 | option3 option4)

But this doesn't make it generic and adding one more option will require listing of 6 permutation of the options.
Is there an easy way of doing it?

Comment: See also Jim's answer at google groups: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/antlr-discussion/3F8f4eYOS6k

Answer (score 3):

You should make your grammar generic. Don't hardcode option names in the grammar, but generate a generic lexer and then interpret option names in your application.

I mean something like this:

```
grammar CommandLine;
command: ID option*;
option: OPTION ID;
OPTION: '-' ID;
ID : [a-zA-Z0-9]+;
```

Then use code to extract option names.